# React router dom v6 , Root path link always active,even when click on other link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, jsx, react-router-dom

i search all over google and could not find any solution, my problem is that i have a classic nav with 
this is a componen called SideBar witch returns this
`

```
 return (
        <motion.div className="font-nunito font-bold bg-gray-dark w-16 h-screen absolute top-0 left-0 bottom-0 z-10 flex flex-col justify-between py-10 ">
            <Link to="/" className="block py-2 px-0 text-center">
                <motion.div
                    className="flex flex-col"
                    initial="hidden"
                    animate="visible"
                    variants={motionNavChildrens}
                >
                    <p className="font-nunito text-xl text-gray-light ">GAR</p>
                    <p className="font-roboto text-xl text-primary">
                        .IS<span className="text-gray-light">()</span>
                    </p>
                </motion.div>
            </Link>
            <NavButtons/>
            <nav className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
                {navSocialButtons.map((item, i) => (
                    <NavLink to={item.link} target="_blank">
                        <item.icon className="h-6 text-lg text-gray-light hover:text-secondary my-1" />
                    </NavLink>
                ))}
            </nav>
        </motion.div>
    );
```

`
but the problem is on the  component...

```
<nav className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-center ">
            <motion.div
                className={`text-3xl text-gray-light  h-12 relative self-center flex items-center justify-center group ease-out`}
                initial="hidden"
                animate="visible"
                variants={motionNavChildrens}
            >
                <NavLink
                    to="/"
                    className={({ isActive }) =>
                        isActive ? 'active-nav' : 'unselected'
                    }
                    exact="true"
                >
                    <AiOutlineHome className="svg-nav align-middle transition-opacity duration-75 ease-out z-10 " />
                    <span className="span-nav opacity-0 absolute text-xs hover:text-primary ">
                        HOME
                    </span>
                </NavLink>
            </motion.div>

            <motion.div
                className={`text-3xl text-gray-light  h-12 relative self-center flex items-center justify-center group ease-out`}
                initial="hidden"
                animate="visible"
                variants={motionNavChildrens}
            >
                <NavLink
                    to="/about"
                    className={({ isActive }) =>
                        isActive ? 'active-nav' : 'unselected'
                    }
                >
                    <RiUser3Line className="svg-nav align-middle transition-opacity duration-75 ease-out z-10 " />
                    <span className="span-nav opacity-0 absolute text-xs hover:text-primary ">
                        ABOUT
                    </span>
                </NavLink>
            </motion.div>
</nav>
```

its just a sidebar with navlinks, and has some childrens just for syling an icon and a span..i actually have 4 navlink but they are the same as shown.
The links on click, changes the styles...

```
.unselected {
        @apply bg-secondary;
    }
    .active-nav {
        @apply bg-primary;
    }
```

i am using tailwindCss for styling

the fist child that contains the "root" path "/", do not change his styles, it keeps active no matter what, all the others links change its syles with this

```
 className={({ isActive }) =>
                        isActive ? 'active-nav' : 'unselected'
                    }
```

[image]
here you see that the first and thirth are actives

my app.js looks like this

```
return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="App">
                <SideBar />
                    <Routes>
                        <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
                        <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />
                        <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
                        <Route exact path="/mywork" element={<MyWork />} />
                    </Routes>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
```

Comment: Should be `exact={true}` not `exact="true"`

Comment: thanks for answer, still the same issue  :(